# style div with css so it looks exactly like default html select form

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Is there a way how to style a div with css so it looks exactly like its native html select form? . Exactly like in these pictures. no hover[image]  hover [image: select form].
The thing is that I am making multilevel drop dropdown menu in javascript and i want it to look like its standard html select. The only part I am not able to figure out is the arrow with blue gradient on hover. I am not able to position it correctly.

This is my div strcture

```
<div class="multilevel-dropdown-display"><span class="multilevel-dropdown-value"></span> <span class="multilevel-dropdown-arrow"></span></div>
```

I know I have to position the arrow with absolute positioning but if I add another image on hower (I know I should do it with background gradient) its outside the area.

here is the css style for the arrow

```
.multilevel-dropdown-arrow {

    background-image: url("icon.png");
    width:16px; 
    height:18px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;


}
```

Maybe I am doing it all wrong and there is an easier solution for this. I would like it to look really exactly like select form.
Thank you for your help

Comment: I'm using a Mac. My select elements look nothing like the one in your screenshot. Have you considered this?

Comment: To be honest, I forget about it. I think it would be better to restyle every selector I have on the webpage with css

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the arrow inside another div with padding. So, the HTML structure will look like:

```
<div class="multilevel-dropdown-display"><span class="multilevel-dropdown-value"></span> <div class="multilevel-dropdown-arrow-box"><span class="multilevel-dropdown-arrow"></span></div></div>
```

After applying padding and hover effect, CSS will look like -

```
.multilevel-dropdown-arrow-box {border:1px solid transparent;padding-top , padding-bottom: 5px;padding-left , padding-right:3px;}
.multilevel-dropdown-display:hover .multilevel-dropdown-arrow-box {background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,255,0), rgba(0,0,255,0.8));border:1px solid blue;}
```

Note that you'll have to reposition the multilevel-dropdown-arrow-box according to your needs.